# Laravel 5 Search Multi attribute Error

Tags: php, laravel, search, laravel-5

I`m new to the Laravel 5.4 .i needed to develop multiple attributed Search function.Here is the error um getting .
[image]

Here is my registered.index.blade.php View

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-body">

                  <table class="table table-striped">
                  <thead>

                    <th>Full Name</th>
                    <th>Name with initials</th>
                    <th>National ID Number</th>
                    <th>Date Of Birth</th>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody>
                    @foreach($items as $item)
               <tr>
                  <td>{{ $item->full_name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->name_with_initials }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->nic_no }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->date_of_birth }}</td>
              </tr>
                    @endforeach
                  </tbody>
          </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the my Controller .

```
public function search_code(Request $request){
$query = $request->search;
$queryType = $request->institute; // 'id' or 'name'
$items = DB::table('registerdetails');        

if($queryType == 'id'){
  $items = $items->where('id', 'LIKE',"%$query%");
}
if($queryType == 'name'){
  $items = $items->where('name', 'LIKE',"%$query%");
}
$items->get();

return view('registeredusers.index')->with('items',$items);

        }
```

Can Anyone suggest me the solution for this error?

Comment: what will dd($item) show?

Comment: return view('registeredusers.index')->with('items',$items->get());

Comment: Print item result and check data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$items->get();
```

To this:

```
$items = $items->get();
```

When you're doing just `$items->get();`, the `$items` variable has an instance of Query Builder and not query result.

Comment: Sir,Now there is no any errors but search not functioning properly.can you see that why ?

Comment: search dos`t filter.it shows all the data.not filtered them by id or its name

Comment: Ok, please show me the result of `dd($request->search, $request->institute)` and `dd($items)`

Comment: Dear sir what do you want? i did`t understand what you asking

Comment: To be able to help you, I need to see the result of two commands I've shown above. `dd()` function shows dump of data.

Comment: As because of um new to the Laravel.i don`t understand what you are saying.if you able to give the code may i need to run it will be very helpful .

Comment: sir can you please help me?

Comment: I gave you the code, `dd` is all you need to print data dump.

Comment: sir i ll ask it as a another question bcz i dont understand what you aresaying.thank u for the help